# Is there a function similar to string compare but for integers?

Tags: c

I want to allow the user to enter a variable amount, and then compare that amount to my array of percentages. And then display ALL amounts in my percentages array equal to OR greater than that number the user entered. I would also like to do this for a lower amount, but they should be the same I would think. If anyone can provide any insight I would appreciate it! Code will be attached underneath.. (Please let me know if I can clarify anything)

```
/*
10/31/2017
FOOTBALL STATS
*/

#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_TEAM 30
#define LEN_NAME 40

void displayWelcome(void);
void calcPercent(double percentages[], int elements, int wins[], int losses[], int ties[]);
void showAll (char name[], char league[], char division[], int wins, int  losses, int ties, double percentages);
void displayExit(void);

int main (void)
{
//Display welcome message
displayWelcome();

char name[NUM_TEAM][LEN_NAME] = {0};
char division[NUM_TEAM][LEN_NAME] = {0};
char league[NUM_TEAM][LEN_NAME] = {0};
char line[LEN_NAME];
char menu, again;

int wins[NUM_TEAM] = {0};
int losses[NUM_TEAM] = {0};
int ties[NUM_TEAM] = {0};
int i = 0, count, sum, percentQuery;

double percentages[NUM_TEAM] = {0};
;

FILE * filePtr;

filePtr = fopen("C:\\Users\\thoma\\NFLTeams.txt", "r");
if (filePtr == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to open file\n");
}
else
{
    while (i < NUM_TEAM && fgets( line, sizeof(line), filePtr) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(line, "%s%s%s%i%i%i",name[i], league[i], division[i], &wins[i], &losses[i], &ties[i]);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(filePtr);
    count = i;
}
//^ end reading in file

//Calculate win percentages
calcPercent( percentages, count, wins, losses, ties);

//Main menu loop
do
{
    //Ask user how they would like to search
    printf("Please choose an option from the following menu:"
           "\n-Enter 'a' to display all information contained in the database"
           "\n-OR Enter 'b' to search by league"
           "\n-OR Enter 'c' to search by division"
           "\n-OR Enter 'd' to search by wins above a certain percentage"
           "\n-OR Enter 'e' to search by wins below a certain percentage: ");
    scanf("\n%c", &menu);

    //If user chooses a
    if (menu == 'a')
    {
        //Display all of database
        for (i = 0; i <= count - 1; i = i + 1)
        {
            showAll(name[i], league[i], division[i], wins[i], losses[i], ties[i], percentages[i]);
        }
    }
    //If user chooses b
    else if (menu == 'b')
    {
        // Propmt user to choose AFC or NFC
        printf("\nPlease choose from the following menu:\nEnter 'a' to search for teams in the AFC league \nOR enter 'b' to search for teams in the NFC league: ");
        // scan for what the user entered
        scanf("\n%c", &menu);
        //Display option for AFC
        if (menu == 'a')
        {
            for (i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1 )
            {
                if (strcmp (league[i], "AFC") == 0)
                {
                    printf("Here are the standings for the teams in the AFC division:\n");
                    printf("Team Name: %s \nLeague: %s\nDivision: %s\nWins: %i Losses: %i Ties: %i\nWin Rate: %.2lf%%\n\n", name[i], league[i], division[i], wins[i], losses[i], ties[i], percentages[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else
            //Display option for NFC
        {
            for (i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1 )
            {
                if (strcmp (league[i], "NFC") == 0)
                {
                    printf("Here are the standings for the teams in the NFC division:\n");
                    printf("Team Name: %s \nLeague: %s\nDivision: %s\nWins: %i Losses: %i Ties: %i\nWin Rate: %.2lf%%\n\n", name[i], league[i], division[i], wins[i], losses[i], ties[i], percentages[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //If user chooses c
    else if (menu == 'c')
    {
        printf("\nPlease choose an option from the following menu: \nEnter 'a' if you would like to search for North division standings\n"
               "OR enter 'b' to search for East division standings\nOR enter 'c' to search for South division standings\nOR enter"
               " 'd' to search for West division standings: ");
        scanf("\n%c", &menu);

        if (menu == 'a')
        {
            for (i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1 )
            {
                if (strcmp (division[i], "North") == 0)
                {
                    printf("Here are the standings for the teams in the North division:\n");
                    printf("Team Name: %s \nLeague: %s\nWins: %i Losses: %i Ties: %i\nWin Rate: %.2lf%%\n\n", name[i], league[i], wins[i], losses[i], ties[i], percentages[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (menu == 'b')

        {
            for (i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1 )
            {
                if (strcmp (division[i], "East") == 0)
                {
                    printf("Here are the standings for the teams in the East division:\n");
                    printf("Team Name: %s \nLeague: %s\nWins: %i Losses: %i Ties: %i\nWin Rate: %.2lf%%\n\n", name[i], league[i], wins[i], losses[i], ties[i], percentages[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (menu == 'c')

        {
            for (i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1 )
            {
                if (strcmp (division[i], "South") == 0)
                {
                    printf("Here are the standings for the teams in the South division:\n");
                    printf("Team Name: %s \nLeague: %s\nWins: %i Losses: %i Ties: %i\nWin Rate: %.2lf%%\n\n", name[i], league[i], wins[i], losses[i], ties[i], percentages[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (menu == 'd')

        {
            for (i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1 )
            {
                if (strcmp (division[i], "West") == 0)
                {
                    printf("Here are the standings for the teams in the West division:\n");
                    printf("Team Name: %s \nLeague: %s\nWins: %i Losses: %i Ties: %i\nWin Rate: %.2lf%%\n\n", name[i], league[i], wins[i], losses[i], ties[i], percentages[i]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    //if user chooses d
    else if (menu == 'd')
    {
       /* UNFINISHED.. COULD NOT FIGURE OUT SYNTAX
       My goal was to compare my percentages array to the value that the user inputted (which was stored in the variable 'percentQuery' and display values that were greater than or equal to my percent
                                                                                        Query
        printf("In this menu, you may search for a win percentage above a certain amount.\n"
               "Please enter the amount you would like to search ABOVE: ");
        scanf("\n%d", &percentQuery);

        for (i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1 )
    {
                //I could not figure out the syntax for comparing to see if it was greater than or equal to percentQuery
               if (strcmp (percentages[i], percentQuery) == 0)
                    {
                printf("Here are the standings for the teams with a win percent above %i%%"), percentQuery;
                printf("Team Name: %s \nLeague: %s\nWins: %i Losses: %i Ties: %i\nWin Rate: %.2lf%%\n\n", name[i], league[i], wins[i], losses[i], ties[i], percentages[i]);
            }
        }*/
    }
    //if user chooses e
    else if (menu == 'e')
    {
         /* UNFINISHED.. COULD NOT FIGURE OUT SYNTAX
       My goal was to compare my percentages array to the value that the user inputted (which was stored in the variable 'percentQuery' and display values that were less than or equal to my percent
                                                                                        Query
        printf("In this menu, you may search for a win percentage below a certain amount.\n"
               "Please enter the amount you would like to search BELOW: ");
        scanf("\n%d", &percentQuery);
        for (i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1 )
    {
              //  I could not figure out the syntax for comparing to see if it was less than or equal to percentQuery
               if (strcmp (percentages[i], percentQuery) == 0)
                    {
                printf("Here are the standings for the teams with a win percent below %i%%"), percentQuery;
                printf("Team Name: %s \nLeague: %s\nWins: %i Losses: %i Ties: %i\nWin Rate: %.2lf%%\n\n", name[i], league[i], wins[i], losses[i], ties[i], percentages[i]);
            }
        }*/
    }

    //Prompt user for replay of main menu
 printf("\nWould you like to return to the main menu?\n"
           "Enter (y)es or (n)o: ");
           scanf("\n%c", &again);

}
 while (again == 'y');



//whatever the user types in, strcmp to our data base and set it equal to that.
displayExit();
return 0;
}

void displayWelcome(void)
{
printf("Welcome to my Football Stats.\n\n");
}

void calcPercent(double percentages[], int count, int wins[], int losses[], int ties[])
{
int i, sum;
for (i = 0; i <= count -1; i = i + 1)
{
    sum = wins[i] + losses[i] + ties[i];
    percentages[i] = ((double) wins[i] / sum) * 100;
}
}
void showAll (char name[], char league[], char division[], int wins, int  losses, int ties, double percentages)
{
printf("Team Name: %s \nLeague: %s\nDivision: %s\nWins: %i Losses: %i Ties: %i\nWin Rate: %.2lf%%\n\n", name, league, division, wins, losses, ties, percentages);
}

void displayExit(void)
{
printf("\nThese results were brought to you by.");
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, as long as you have the value the user entered as a float or double, you can then use normal comparators: <, >, ==, !=, <=, >=

Comment: Aside about `scanf("\n%c", &menu);` You are filtering newline, suppose there were **two** newlines or just a space before the next entry? The proper way to filter *whitespace* with the `%c` format (`%d` and `%s` etc filter it anyway) is to use a space, such as `scanf(" %c", &menu);`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @IlarioPierbattista this wasn't a debugging question.. what you are referring to was commented out and not a part of the compiled program.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `>=` operator for "above or equal" and `<` for "below":

```
if (percentages[i] >= percentQuery) {
    /* ... */
}
```

`percentages` is an array of doubles, not strings.